# JMSMessage selector

Tags: java

I want to browse a particular message form the JMS queue.
 My `JMSMessageID` value is "`ID:P<327631.1450267519561.0>`". 
If I set filter as String filter = "`JMSMessageID LIKE 'ID:P<327631%'`"; Browser doesn't find any message from JMS queue.

But If I set String filter = "JMSMessageID LIKE 'ID:%'"; Then it is working fine and browse the respective message from the JMS queue. It seems it doesn't work due to the special characters like ":" and "<".

Please suggest.

```
String filter = "JMSMessageID  LIKE 'ID:P<327631%'";

QueueBrowser browser = qsession.createBrowser(queue,filter);
```

Comment: Your LIKE clause contains %, while your JMSMessageID doesn't. That could be the issue.

Comment: Sorry Tom i have missed % in the second statement, while I posting it. But it actually works for String filter = "JMSMessageID LIKE 'ID:%'"; % indicates any sequence of characters after ID:. But same is not working for String filter = "JMSMessageID LIKE 'ID:P<327631%'"; Why?  Please suggest